# What does "须发皆张" mean?

Tags: meaning

> 须发皆张

须 - Beard

发 - Hair

皆 - All

张 - Spread/Open up

If it was directly translated, it would be something like "[someone's] beard and hair all spread open", but what does that even mean?

I can't really imagine how the person would look, so would the person have hair and a beard that stood up, like how someone would after their hair was affected by static electricity?

Comment: Interesting. I guess it may describe someone with totally disheveled beard and hair.

Answer (score 5):

言未訖，只見關公口開目動，鬚髮皆張，操驚倒

Before he had finished speaking, he looked at Lord Guan and saw: 
His mouth was open, his eyes were starting,
His beard and hair were all bristling and crackling!

Cao Cao was petrified with fear.

Comment: 很有意思！原文來自三國演義吧？

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a furious cat ready for fighting, what will it do? It will "须发皆张".

Answer (score -1):

A literal translation: beard and hair both stand on the ends.

Metaphorical meaning: to describe someone is displaying extreme anger.